# Timing Calculations for Opengl ES 2.0 draw calls

Tags: performance, opengl-es2, linux, timing

I am drawing a cube in OpenGL ES 2.0 in Linux.
I am calculating the time taken for each frame  using below function

```
#define NANO 1000000000

#define NANO_TO_MICRO(x) ((x)/1000)

uint64_t getTick()
{
  struct timespec stCT;
  clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &stCT);
  uint64_t iCurrTimeNano = (1000000000 * stCT.tv_sec + stCT.tv_nsec); // in Nano Secs
  uint64_t iCurrTimeMicro = NANO_TO_MICRO(iCurrTimeNano); // in Micro Secs

  return iCurrTimeMicro;
}
```

I am running my code for 100 frames with simple x-axis rotation.
I am getting around 200 to 220 microsecs per frame.

that means am i getting around (1/220microsec = 4545) FPS
Is my GPU is that fast?
I strongly doubt this result.

what went wrong in the code?

Comment: after including eglswapbuffers for time calculations, my fps comes with 50 to 60. Why eglswapbuffers is taking more than 90% of my frame time ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you calling `glFinish()` after each render pass? That call makes sure that the GPU has actually finished working. OpenGL calls submit the data/command to the GPU and return.

Otherwise, depending on the particulars of your rendering code and the GPU you have, you may get to those figures. Use `glxgears` and see if the values it reports are around your FPS.